# Basler Pylon to GStreamer to multicast UDP

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am attempting to use GStreamer to send captured images from a Basler acA720-290gm GigE camera to multiple clients over UDP multicast. I have been able to acquire the images using the Pylon 7.1.0.25066 API and send them through a GStreamer pipeline consisting of appsrc, videoconvert and ximagesink. However, if I try to add elements to convert the stream to RTP and back, then I only get a single static image.

This code successfully displays the stream on Debian 11. I'm not sure if I can use something other than GRAY8 for the appsrc caps format or not.

Test.cpp

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>

#include <gst/gst.h>

#include "unistd.h"
#include "pthread.h"

pthread_t thread_1;
pthread_t thread_2;

Pylon::CPylonImage image;

bool image_valid = false;
bool gstreamer_thread_done = false;

void* pylon_thread(void*) {
    Pylon::CDeviceInfo device_info;
    Pylon::CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;

    Pylon::PylonAutoInitTerm autoInitTerm;

    device_info.SetIpAddress("192.168.1.109");

    while (1) {
        if (gstreamer_thread_done) { break; }
        try {
            Pylon::CInstantCamera camera(Pylon::CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateDevice(device_info));

            camera.StartGrabbing(Pylon::GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly);

            while (camera.IsGrabbing()) {
                if (gstreamer_thread_done) { break; }
                camera.RetrieveResult(5000, ptrGrabResult, Pylon::TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);

                if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded()) {
                    image.CopyImage(ptrGrabResult);
                    image_valid = true;
                }
                else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %u %s\n", ptrGrabResult->GetErrorCode(), ptrGrabResult->GetErrorDescription().c_str());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (const Pylon::GenericException &e) {
            fprintf(stderr, "An exception occurred.\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.GetDescription());

            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


struct gstreamer_data {
    GstElement* appsrc1;
    GstElement* videoconvert1;
    GstElement* ximagesink1;
    GstElement* pipeline;
    GMainLoop* main_loop;
    guint source_id;
};

static gboolean push_data(gstreamer_data* data) {
    GstBuffer* buffer;
    GstFlowReturn ret;

    buffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped_full(
        (GstMemoryFlags) GST_MEMORY_FLAG_PHYSICALLY_CONTIGUOUS, (gpointer) image.GetBuffer(), image.GetImageSize(), 0, image.GetImageSize(), NULL, NULL
    );

    g_signal_emit_by_name(data->appsrc1, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static void start_feed(GstElement* source, guint size, gstreamer_data* data) {
    (void) source;
    (void) size;

    if (data->source_id == 0) {
        //g_print("Start feeding\n");
        data->source_id = g_idle_add((GSourceFunc) push_data, data);
    }
}

static void stop_feed(GstElement* source, gstreamer_data* data) {
    (void) source;

    if (data->source_id != 0) {
        //g_print("Stop feeding\n");
        g_source_remove(data->source_id);
        data->source_id = 0;
    }
}

static void error_cb(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* msg, gstreamer_data* data) {
    (void) bus;
    GError* err;
    gchar* debug_info;

    gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
    g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
    g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
    g_clear_error(&err);
    g_free(debug_info);

    g_main_loop_quit(data->main_loop);
}

void* gstreamer_thread(void*) {
    gstreamer_data data;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    GstBus* bus;


    data.source_id = 0;

    gst_init(NULL, NULL);

    data.appsrc1 = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "appsrc1");

    g_object_set(
        G_OBJECT(data.appsrc1),
        "stream-type", 0,
        "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
        "is-live", TRUE,
        NULL
    );

    g_object_set(
        G_OBJECT(data.appsrc1),
        "caps", gst_caps_new_simple(
            "video/x-raw",
            "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "GRAY8",
            "width", G_TYPE_INT, image.GetWidth(),
            "height", G_TYPE_INT, image.GetHeight(),
            "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 0, 1,
            NULL
        ),
        NULL
    );

    g_signal_connect(data.appsrc1, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(start_feed), &data);
    g_signal_connect(data.appsrc1, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK(stop_feed), &data);

    data.videoconvert1 = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "videoconvert1");

    data.ximagesink1 = gst_element_factory_make("ximagesink", "ximagesink1");

    data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

    if (
        !data.pipeline ||
        !data.appsrc1 ||
        !data.videoconvert1 ||
        !data.ximagesink1
    )
    {
        g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    gst_bin_add_many (
        GST_BIN(data.pipeline),
        data.appsrc1,
        data.videoconvert1,
        data.ximagesink1,
        NULL
    );

    if (
        gst_element_link_many (
            data.appsrc1,
            data.videoconvert1,
            data.ximagesink1,
            NULL
        ) != TRUE
    )
    {
        g_printerr("Elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
        exit(-1);
    }

    bus = gst_element_get_bus(data.pipeline);
    gst_bus_add_signal_watch(bus);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (bus), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    ret = gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
        exit(-1);
    }

    data.main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run(data.main_loop);

    printf("Exiting.\n");

    gstreamer_thread_done = true;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    int error;

    error = pthread_create(&thread_1, NULL, pylon_thread, NULL);
    if (error) {
        printf("Error: pthread_create: %i\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (image_valid == false) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    error = pthread_create(&thread_2, NULL, gstreamer_thread, NULL);
    if (error) {
        printf("Error: pthread_create: %i\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_join(thread_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
# Makefile for Basler pylon sample program
.PHONY: all clean

# The program to build
NAME       := Test

# Installation directories for pylon
PYLON_ROOT ?= /opt/pylon

# Build tools and flags
LD         := $(CXX)
CPPFLAGS   := $(shell $(PYLON_ROOT)/bin/pylon-config --cflags) $(shell pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0) $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv4) -DUSE_GIGE
CXXFLAGS   := #e.g., CXXFLAGS=-g -O0 for debugging
LDFLAGS    := $(shell $(PYLON_ROOT)/bin/pylon-config --libs-rpath)
LDLIBS     := $(shell $(PYLON_ROOT)/bin/pylon-config --libs) $(shell pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0) -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread

# Rules for building
all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(NAME).o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

$(NAME).o: $(NAME).cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(NAME).o $(NAME)
```

This code displays just a single image:

Test.cpp

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>

#include <gst/gst.h>

#include "unistd.h"
#include "pthread.h"

pthread_t thread_1;
pthread_t thread_2;

Pylon::CPylonImage image;

bool image_valid = false;
bool gstreamer_thread_done = false;

void* pylon_thread(void*) {
    Pylon::CDeviceInfo device_info;
    Pylon::CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;

    Pylon::PylonAutoInitTerm autoInitTerm;

    device_info.SetIpAddress("192.168.1.109");

    while (1) {
        if (gstreamer_thread_done) { break; }
        try {
            Pylon::CInstantCamera camera(Pylon::CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateDevice(device_info));

            camera.StartGrabbing(Pylon::GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly);

            while (camera.IsGrabbing()) {
                if (gstreamer_thread_done) { break; }
                camera.RetrieveResult(5000, ptrGrabResult, Pylon::TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);

                if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded()) {
                    image.CopyImage(ptrGrabResult);
                    image_valid = true;
                }
                else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %u %s\n", ptrGrabResult->GetErrorCode(), ptrGrabResult->GetErrorDescription().c_str());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (const Pylon::GenericException &e) {
            fprintf(stderr, "An exception occurred.\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.GetDescription());

            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


struct gstreamer_data {
    GstElement* appsrc1;
    GstElement* videoconvert1;
    GstElement* x264enc1;
    GstElement* rtph264pay1;
    GstElement* rtph264depay1;
    GstElement* avdec_h2641;
    GstElement* videoconvert2;
    GstElement* ximagesink1;
    GstElement* pipeline;
    GMainLoop* main_loop;
    guint source_id;
};

static gboolean push_data(gstreamer_data* data) {
    GstBuffer* buffer;
    GstFlowReturn ret;

    buffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped_full(
        (GstMemoryFlags) GST_MEMORY_FLAG_PHYSICALLY_CONTIGUOUS, (gpointer) image.GetBuffer(), image.GetImageSize(), 0, image.GetImageSize(), NULL, NULL
    );

    g_signal_emit_by_name(data->appsrc1, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static void start_feed(GstElement* source, guint size, gstreamer_data* data) {
    (void) source;
    (void) size;

    if (data->source_id == 0) {
        g_print("Start feeding\n");
        data->source_id = g_idle_add((GSourceFunc) push_data, data);
    }
}

static void stop_feed(GstElement* source, gstreamer_data* data) {
    (void) source;

    if (data->source_id != 0) {
        g_print("Stop feeding\n");
        g_source_remove(data->source_id);
        data->source_id = 0;
    }
}

static void error_cb(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* msg, gstreamer_data* data) {
    (void) bus;
    GError* err;
    gchar* debug_info;

    gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
    g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
    g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
    g_clear_error(&err);
    g_free(debug_info);

    g_main_loop_quit(data->main_loop);
}

void* gstreamer_thread(void*) {
    gstreamer_data data;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    GstBus* bus;


    data.source_id = 0;

    gst_init(NULL, NULL);

    data.appsrc1 = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "appsrc1");

    g_object_set(
        G_OBJECT(data.appsrc1),
        "stream-type", 0,
        "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
        "is-live", TRUE,
        NULL
    );

    g_object_set(
        G_OBJECT(data.appsrc1),
        "caps", gst_caps_new_simple(
            "video/x-raw",
            "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "GRAY8",
            "width", G_TYPE_INT, image.GetWidth(),
            "height", G_TYPE_INT, image.GetHeight(),
            "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 0, 1,
            NULL
        ),
        NULL
    );

    g_signal_connect(data.appsrc1, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(start_feed), &data);
    g_signal_connect(data.appsrc1, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK(stop_feed), &data);

    data.videoconvert1 = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "videoconvert1");
    data.x264enc1 = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "x264enc1");
    data.rtph264pay1 = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "rtph264pay1");
    data.rtph264depay1 = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264depay", "rtph264depay1");
    data.avdec_h2641 = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264", "avdec_h2641");
    data.videoconvert2 = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "videoconvert2");
    data.ximagesink1 = gst_element_factory_make("ximagesink", "ximagesink1");

    data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

    if (
        !data.pipeline ||
        !data.appsrc1 ||
        !data.videoconvert1 ||
        !data.x264enc1 ||
        !data.rtph264pay1 ||
        !data.rtph264depay1 ||
        !data.avdec_h2641 ||
        !data.videoconvert2 ||
        !data.ximagesink1
    )
    {
        g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    gst_bin_add_many (
        GST_BIN(data.pipeline),
        data.appsrc1,
        data.videoconvert1,
        data.x264enc1,
        data.avdec_h2641,
        data.videoconvert2,
        data.ximagesink1,
        NULL
    );

    if (
        gst_element_link_many (
            data.appsrc1,
            data.videoconvert1,
            data.x264enc1,
            data.avdec_h2641,
            data.videoconvert2,
            data.ximagesink1,
            NULL
        ) != TRUE
    )
    {
        g_printerr("Elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
        exit(-1);
    }

    bus = gst_element_get_bus(data.pipeline);
    gst_bus_add_signal_watch(bus);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (bus), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    ret = gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
        exit(-1);
    }

    data.main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run(data.main_loop);

    printf("Exiting.\n");

    gstreamer_thread_done = true;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    int error;

    error = pthread_create(&thread_1, NULL, pylon_thread, NULL);
    if (error) {
        printf("Error: pthread_create: %i\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (image_valid == false) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    error = pthread_create(&thread_2, NULL, gstreamer_thread, NULL);
    if (error) {
        printf("Error: pthread_create: %i\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_join(thread_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of copying image from PtrGrabResult To CPylonImage, try with alternate method of receiving buffers: through `image.AttachGrabResultBuffer()` method. It is well used in `GUI_ImageWindow` sample project of Pylon SDK.